# Execute UIControllerview with no segue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

I would like to execute a `UIViewController` from a `UIActionSheet` I mean I have a `UIActionSheet` with three buttons and one of these button I want to execute a `UIViewController`.

Is possible? How?

Best regards,
Oriol

Comment: To clarify, by "execute" do you mean present it to the user with its views?  (As opposed to calling some method inside it, that is.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006799

You'll want to implement the `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method and push your `UIViewController` from there.